# using requirejs - not able to extend the jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying to extend the jquery in the require define function. but i am not able to extend. any one help me to sort this:

here is my code :

```
define(['jquery'],function($){

    // $ available here.

    $.fn.extend({
        valid : function () {
            console.log('validate now');
        }
    });
    console.log($.valid); //console as undefined-why?
});
```

Comment: Have you tried `$.valid = function() {}` or `$.extend({valid: function() {}})`. All methods stored on `$.fn` is accasable when doing `$(selector).fnMethod()`

Comment: let me try with your approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Like NULL said, I used this way:

```
$.extend({valid: function() {}})
```

It works fine. thanks every one!